# Using Paho Python: Why the callback “on_message” is not triggered?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I don’t understand why the callback “on_message” is not triggered when a message is published correctly in the same topic that i’m subscribed.
This the code I used:

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    """ Callback called when connection/reconnection is detected """
    print("Connect %s result is: %s" % (host, rc))

    # With Paho, always subscribe at on_connect (if you want to
    # subscribe) to ensure you resubscribe if connection is
    # lost.
    client.subscribe("some/message/to/publish")

    if rc == 0:
        client.connected_flag = True
        print("connected OK")
        return

    print("Failed to connect to %s, error was, rc=%s" % rc)
    # handle error here
    sys.exit(-1)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    """ Callback called for every PUBLISH received """
    print("%s => %s" % (msg.topi, str(msg.payload)))


# Define clientId, host, user and password
client = mqtt.Client(client_id=client_id, clean_session=clean_session)
client.username_pw_set(user_name, password)
client.subscribe("some/message/to/publish")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

# connect using standard unsecure MQTT with keepalive to 60
client.connect(host, port, keepalive=60)
client.connected_flag = False
while not client.connected_flag:  # wait in loop
    client.loop()
    time.sleep(1)

client.subscribe("some/message/to/publish")
# publish message (optionally configuring qos=1, qos=2 and retain=True/False)
ret = client.publish("some/message/to/publish", "{'status' : 'on'}")
client.loop()

print("Publish operation finished with ret=%s" % ret)

client.disconnect()
```

This the exit code I’ve got:

```
Connect node02.myqtthub.com result is: 0
connected OK
Publish operation finished with ret=(0, 3)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If possible can you put parts of the code that you think are relevant into the actual question for future readers of this post (the imgur posts may expire)? I can see why you've done this though as the first is pretty long, so makes sense to leave the links in too.

Comment: As @Nick asked, please do not post images of code or error messages. Images are hard to read and impossible for people that use screen readers. Please post the text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `client.loop()` only processes a single iteration of the client's network event processor.

The call to `client.publish()` can take multiple events to complete (depending on the size of the message and the QOS being used) and will be totally separate from handling the message when the broker sends it back to the client.
The call to `client.subscribe()` will also consume at least one event loop call.
So the single call to `client.loop()` will not be enough.

Unless you have a really good idea about what you are doing you should probably be using the `client.start_loop()`/`client.stop_loop()` functions to run the event processing loop on a separate thread.